# Polygon animation with rotation, using build modifier

Tags: animation, modifiers, build-modifier

I'm making buid-on animation on several meshes using build modifier. Is there any way to add rotation property to this kind of animation? I would like to rotate the faces as they show up.

Comment: Not with the build modifier. Have a look at [animation nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes) - you can see that effect in the new [demo reel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCghhlMOwRg)